# Jenkins's AWS Spot Fleet plugin cannot load AWS credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I have been using the Amazon EC2 plugin for months, everything working fine.

Now I just realized there is a plugin for Spot Fleet, so I wanted to give it a try. I configured all the parameters, but upon testing a connection, I get:

```
Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@5c06b89: No AWS profile named 'default', com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@2f169e09: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint]
```

One might think, well it's crystal clear, it can't load the credentials... However, the credentials are fine, because they are the same credentials used with the other plugin, and **they are the same credentials used on the initial configuration of this plugin**, when it uses the credentials to get from AWS the list of active Spot Fleet requests... I mean, the plugin is already using the credentials so it can actually load them.

So, what might be causing this error?

Info about the plugin is available at https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/06/10/save-costs-with-ec2-spot-fleet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems to be a bug in the plugin's test connection function.

As I said, I didn't understand why it was complaining if it was using the credentials already, so I decided to forget about that error and launch my jobs, and they were running fine on the EC2 spots.